# Why when I use text to column Excel changes my numbers

Tags: excel

For example I have this line right here:

> -2.7769,-5.6967,5.9179,0.37671,1

When I convert text to column using as delimiter comma in preview I see the result just right:

> -2.7769   -5.6967 5.9179  0.37671 1

But when I press confirm I get this:

> -27.769   -56.967 59.179  0.37671 1

How can I stop it from doing that and get the desired outcome?

I tried to make a line separated with commas into columns using the text to column feature from excel but I didn't get the result I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the entire solution, but I clearly see that you are mixing up decimal delimiter and thousand delimiter:

I guess that you mean "-2.7769" meaning "minus two, followed by a decimal separator, followed by .7769 (a number between zero and one)", but what your computer understand is: "minus twenty-seven thousand, seven hundred and sixty-nine, but the user has put the thousand separator at the wrong place. I will correct this."

In order to check whether or not your Excel is using a thousand separator, you can ask a random cell's formatting (right-click, choose "Format cells"): the "Use 1000 Separator (,)" checkbox in the "Number" chapter should be unchecked, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what  I was trying to say